# Quit VPN before Auto Shutdown

Tags: vpn

I have the Mac mini to shutdown at a specific time. However I have a VPN running, and when the Mac shuts down, the VPN asks "Yes or No." Since I'm not in front of the mac, it keeps the shut down from happening.

Any ideas? It's been 20 years since I used any scripting, so even that i would need help with.

Comment: Please add the VPN service/app you are usin' - (on-board OS X VPN or 3rd-party app?)!

Comment: It is the beta version of the NordVPN app.